# Why is `"literal"` encouraged to decay to `const char*` in C++ argument type match?

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm playing around with overloading operators in c++14, and I tried to match two types of arguments: any-old-const-char*, and a-string-literal.

That is, I'm trying to see if I can discriminate between:

```
const char * run_time;
```

and

```
"compile time"
```

I wrote the code below, and as shown, when I try `span >> "literal"` it invoked the `const char*` function.

When I `#if 0`-out the `const char*` version, the template version gets called just fine.

If I change the template version to take an rvalue-reference (&&) parameter for `literal`, it doesn't compile.

If I add a `const char (&literal)[]` non-template version, the `const char*` version is still preferred. Removing the const-char* version, the template version is preferred.

Can you explain this? In particular:

1. Why is `const char*` preferred over `const char (&)[N]`?
2. Why is `const char (&)[N]` preferred over `const char (&)[]` (non-template)?
3. Why is `const char (&&)[N]` unable to compile?
4. Is there a "right way" to capture literal strings?

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <gsl/gsl>
#include <type_name.h++>

template<unsigned N>
auto
operator>>(gsl::span<const char*,-1>& spn, const char (&literal)[N])
    -> gsl::span<const char*, -1>&
{
    cout << "Got array: " << literal << endl;
    return spn;
}

auto
operator>>(gsl::span<const char*,-1>& spn, const char *literal)
    -> gsl::span<const char*, -1>&
{
    cout << "Got const-char*: " << literal << endl;
    return spn;
}
#if 0
#endif

int
main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    auto spn = gsl::span<const char*>(argv, argc);

    cout << type_name<decltype(spn)>() << endl; // gsl::span<const char *, -1>

    cout << type_name<decltype("literal")>() << endl; // char const (&)[8]

    cout << type_name<decltype(("literal"))>() << endl; // char const (&)[8]

    auto helpx = "literal";
    cout << type_name<decltype(helpx)>() << endl; // const char *


    spn >> "literal"; // Got const-char*: literal

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

In case it matters, I'm compiling with:

```
c++ --std=c++14 -Iinclude   -c -o main.o main.c++
```

And c++ says:

```
$ c++ --version
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: My guess is that it is chosen as it is non-template. Non templates are always preffered overloads.

Comment: yes, a non-template overload is preferred over a template overload

Comment: On the other hand rvalue question is quite intruiging for me and can't wait to see the full answer...

Comment: @bolov: only if otherwise equally good

Comment: IIRC `const char (&)[]` cannot bind to a value of type `const char [N]`

Comment: The gsl stuff appears irrelevant. Please remove it if unnecessary. If it is relevant, the question would be more subtle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why is `const char*` preferred over `const char (&)[N]`?

The reason for this is rather technical. Even though the decay of a string literal from `const char[N]` to `const char*` is a conversion, it falls into the "lvalue transformation" category and is therefore considered by [over.ics.rank]/3 to be as good as no conversion at all. Since "no conversion" is required for either overload, the non-template overload wins.

> Why is `const char (&)[N]` preferred over `const char (&)[]` (non-template)?

It is not possible to bind a *reference to array of unknown bound* to a value of type *array of known bound*. Instead, a reference to array of unknown bound can only be bound to values that are themselves arrays of unknown bound.

> Why is `const char (&&)[N]` unable to compile?

A string literal is an lvalue so I'm not sure why you would expect this to work.

> Is there a "right way" to capture literal strings?

You can use a helper function template that captures its argument using a forwarding reference so as to not destroy any type information (`const char*` versus `const char[N]`) then dispatch on the type using template specialization. You'll probably also want to use SFINAE to make sure it is disabled if anything other than a `const char*` or `const char[N]` is passed in. To wit,

```
template <bool b>
struct f_helper;

template <>
struct f_helper<true> {
    void do_it(const char*) {
        puts("pointer");
    }
};

template <>
struct f_helper<false> {
    template <std::size_t N>
    void do_it(const char (&)[N]) {
        printf("array of length %zd\n", N);
    }
};

template <class T, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<char*, std::decay_t<T>>::value ||
                                                   std::is_same<const char*, std::decay_t<T>>::value>::type>
void f(T&& s) {
    f_helper<std::is_pointer<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value>{}.do_it(s);
}
```

Coliru link: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e9681868d715e87

Comment: You haven't seen [my paper](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0388r0.html). :P I'm currently revising, but it passed Evolution.

Comment: @Columbo I'm surprised, why haven't you mentioned that in C, `int[]` is even compatible to `int[N]`, with their composite type being the latter? That's a very good motivation to allow it, IMO.

Comment: @Columbo is it intentional that this selects the `char` variant? `void f(char(&&)[]); void f(int(&&)[2]); f({10});`. Intuitively, I would have expected it to select the `int` variant. The "N is greater than the number of elements"-rule IMO should be a tie-breaker - as you formulated in the last paragraph for the "unknown" vs "known" rule and should IMO not ignore the other type-adjustment being done. Or have I misunderstood something here?

Comment: Note that DR1307 that you quote requires both array base types to be the same. So it will not consider a type adjustment to be less bad than a larger array size.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That is indeed intentional. I gotta check if it was mentioned in the core discussion; I think it was.

Comment: @Columbo IMO that seems to be no good. So it seems that `{ {{1}} }` to `int [2][1][1]` is worse than to `vector<int> [][10]`, based on the rationale that 2 is larger than the toplevel number of elements in the initializer list and the other array is of unknown-bound so that the larger 2 would create a larger array. That rationale does not seem to be useful for this example, because it makes a user defined conversion sequence better than a very cheap standard conversion sequence, in addition to thinking that 2 is larger than 10.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I think there's little point arguing via pathological cases. I can also say prefering `int[2000]` over `char[]` induces overhead (after all, that's what overload resolution seeks to minimize).

Comment: @Columbo the purpose was to overdraw the point so that it becomes apparent what the problem is. That the proposal in the paper ignores any insights that are gained by looking into the element conversion. At that point, you do not know what the element conversion sequences look like, so IMO the OR rule should be conservative and only apply the "larger arrays are worse" if the element types are the same.

Comment: True, it's overhead, but you can at least provide an upper-bound on this overhead that is inverted: it's the over-length of the larger array compared to the smaller array. But if you instead decide to ignore the element-conversion-sequences, you cannot provide an upper-bound on the cost that is being inverted by the rule.

Comment: @Columbo ah I take back my note regarding the user defined conversion. Actually, the `int[2][1][1]` is *better* than the `vector<int> [][10]` because they are of different form (standard vs user defined). So I think it's not *too* bad.

Comment: GCC does not get that right though - it thinks that these special rules for list initialization apply always, instead of only when the forms are equal. Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00ee8040f4435ed4 . Clang compiles the snippet.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Perhaps you should use deleted definitions to make the test well-defined in either case. Either way, we should get like a chat room or sth. if you want to discuss this in depth. :-) (Although probably better PM; exam term forces me to force myself to revise....)

Comment: @Columbo if gcc gives a diagnostic and aborts to compile a valid well-defined program, it gets something wrong though. It doesn't hurt when then in addition it triggers undefined behavior by selecting the wrong function by OR.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb The point is that ill-formed NDR means we could see no problem when in fact there was a problem. It's just general advice, in this case it's clear what is going on, I think.-

Answer (score 1):

1. The overload taking a pointer is preferred because it is not a template according to

> 13.3.3 Best viable function [over.match.best]
>
> Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function
> F2 if for all arguments i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and then
>
> ...
>
> (1.7)
> F1 is not a function template specialization and F2 is a function template specialization

2. actually non-template `const char (&)[]` does not seem to compile at all because it is a reference to a non-bound array. It is possible to pass a pointer like this `const char []`, but not array.
3. this should fail at least for the same reason as (2)
4. you can provide another template taking a reference to pointer:

```
template< typename = void > void
foo(char const * & text)
{
    ::std::cout << "got ptr" << ::std::endl;
}
```

Note that providing another template taking a pointer won't work because both template specializations will be fine and we'll get ambiguous choice of overloaded functions.