# const char array template vs char const* function overload

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overload-resolution

I have looked at all the answers for the suggested related questions that stack overflow presented as I wrote this question, I have googled around, and I have looked at [STL's video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-Cpp-3-of-n) on overload resolution to try and figure out what makes the following code select the `char const*` overload over the template, but I can't figure it out.

```
#include <cstdio>

void foo( int i, char const* c_str_1, char const* c_str_2 )
{
   printf( "foo( int i, char const* c_str_1, char const* c_str_2 )\n" );
}

template< std::size_t N, std::size_t M >
void foo( int i, char const (&c_str_1)[N], char const (&c_str_2)[M] )
{
   printf( "foo( int i, char const (&c_str_1)[N], char const (&c_str_2)[M] )\n" );
}


int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
   char const* c_strg_1 = "This is a c style string.";
   foo( 1, c_strg_1, "bla" );
   foo( 1, "bla", "bla" );
   return 0;
}
```

It probably is something obvious I am missing, but the compiler always selects the `char const*` overload.  I would have thought the template is an exact match and the other one needs a "decay"/"conversion".

Anyhow, thanks to anyone with insight into this.

Comment: Notable, of those two invokes, the only one that *could* be a match to your template is the second. The first is obviously not, and could never be.

Comment: You could also be explicit: `foo<>(1, "bla", "bla");`

Comment: @Barry After posting, I continued looking into this and I have also found this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732122/why-is-literal-encouraged-to-decay-to-const-char-in-c-argument-type-mat) which could be considered a duplicate.  I think I should hit the "That solved my problem" button to accept the duplicate and close the question, but the button does not appear.  Sorry

Answer (score 3):

During the overload resolution usual functions are always preferred over function templates.

It means, that if there is an overload of `foo` which might accept appropriate arguments (even if the function template seems to be a better match), then the compiler will choose this overload.

In addition to that, for the first call:

```
foo( 1, c_strg_1, "bla" );
```

there is no way to instantiate a function template as `c_strg_1` has a type of `const char*`.